# Returning Wrong Details after IDataReader = DbObject.ExecuteReader(DbCommand) 2nd time execution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I'm bit confused this code I don't know where I am doing,

```vb
Public Function CreateAddressDetailDb(ByVal AddressDetailList As IList(Of AddressDetail), ByVal EmployeeID As Integer) As String

    Dim ReturnCode As Boolean = False
    Dim Employeegeneratednumber As String = String.Empty
    Dim ReturnValues As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim DbObject As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()
    Dim DbCommand As DbCommand = DbObject.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_AddressDetial_Create")

    Try
        If Not AddressDetailList Is Nothing And AddressDetailList.Count > 0 Then
            For Each Addressdetaulobject As AddressDetail In AddressDetailList
                With Addressdetaulobject
                    Data.AddInParameter(DbCommand, "paEmployeeID", DbType.Int32, EmployeeID, DbObject)
                    Data.AddInParameter(DbCommand, "paUpdatedBy", DbType.Int16, .Updatedby, DbObject)
                End With

                Using DataReaderObject As IDataReader = DbObject.ExecuteReader(DbCommand)

                    DataReaderObject.Read()
                    ReturnValues("Result") = DataReaderObject.Item("Result")
                    ReturnValues("Employeenumber") = DataReaderObject.Item("Employeenumber")
                    DataReaderObject.Close()
                    If Employeegeneratednumber = String.Empty Or Employeegeneratednumber = "" Then
                        Employeegeneratednumber = CType(ReturnValues("Employeenumber"), String)
                    End If
                End Using
                DbCommand.Parameters.Clear()
            Next
        End If
        If ReturnValues("Result").ToString().Equals("0") Then
            Return Employeegeneratednumber
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        Throw
    End Try
    Return Employeegeneratednumber
End Function
```

When I insert an `Employee` with 1 address I am getting correct `Employeegeneratednumber` but if insert an `Employee` with 2 addresses then I get the old `Employeegeneratednumber` which is not related to current employee.**This issue only occurring in the Production Site not in the Development Site**

Answer (score 0):

SqlDataReader provides a way of reading a forward-only stream of rows from a SQL Server database.

your call `DataReaderObject.Read()` will return first row only instead you have to loop over available rows like below:

```
while (DataReaderObject.Read())
{
     ReturnValues("Result") = DataReaderObject.Item("Result")
     ReturnValues("Employeenumber") = DataReaderObject.Item("Employeenumber")
}
```

You may need to change your logic based on you requirement because above code will always return `Employeenumber` of last row of available rows when you access `ReturnValues("Employeenumber")`.

Comment: when i am trying to insert address1 then getting employeenumber=10 and when i try to insert address2 for same employee i am getting wrong employeenumber. Here i'm passing list of address for same employee